# retraining last layer of inception-v3 significantly slowers the classification

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

In an attempt for transfer learning over inception-v3 with TF and PY3.5, I've tested two approaches:

1- retraining the last layer, as shown here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining

2- Apply linear SVM on top of inception-V3 bottlenecks as demonstrated here: https://www.kernix.com/blog/image-classification-with-a-pre-trained-deep-neural-network_p11

Expectedly, they should've had a similar runtime for classification phase, since the critical part - the bottlenecks extraction - is identical. In practice though, the retrained network is about 8X slower when running classification.

My questions is whether anyone has an idea for the reason of this.

Some code snippets:

SVM on top (the faster):

```
def getTensors():
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    f = open('classify_image_graph_def.pb', 'rb')
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tensorBottleneck, tensorsResizedImage = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='', return_elements=['pool_3/_reshape:0', 'Mul:0'])
    return tensorBottleneck, tensorsResizedImage 

def calc_bottlenecks(imgFile, tensorBottleneck, tensorsResizedImage):
    """ - read, decode and resize to get <resizedImage> - """
    bottleneckValues = sess.run(tensorBottleneck, {tensorsResizedImage : resizedImage})
    return np.squeeze(bottleneckValues)
```

This takes about 0.5 sec on my (Windows) laptop while the SVM part takes no time.

Retraining last layer - (this is harder to summarize since longer code)

```
def loadGraph(pbFile):
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(pbFile, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        softmaxTensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

def labelImage(imageFile, softmaxTensor):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        input_layer_name = 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'
        predictions, = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {input_layer_name: image_data})
```

'pbFile' is the file saved be the retrainer, which supposed to have identical topology and weights excluding the classification layer, as 'classify_image_graph_def.pb'. This takes about 4sec to run (on my same laptop, without the loading).

Any idea for the performance gap?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was in creating a new tf.Session() for every image. Storing the session when reading graph and using it made runtime back to expected.

```
def loadGraph(pbFile):
    ...
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        softmaxTensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
        sessToStore = sess
    return softmaxTensor, sessToStore  

def labelImage(imageFile, softmaxTensor, sessToStore):
    input_layer_name = 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'
    predictions, = sessToStore.run(softmax_tensor, {input_layer_name: image_data})
```